# Django queryset filter based on number of children

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-filter

I'm using Django filters in order to do some filtering for my project. I have the following models:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, models.CASCADE)
```

My query looks like this:

```py
Foo.objects.filter(blah=blah)
```

I want to narrow this filter by only giving me Foo objects that have at least 5 Bar objects connected with it via FK.

So if I have 3 Foo objects which respectively have 7, 5, and 3 Bar objects that have their id, then only the first two should be in the end queryset. How would I do that so that the evaluated queryset only has the first two objects in memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can annotate the number of `Bar` objects, and then filter on these:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Foo.objects.annotate(
    nbar=Count('bar')
).filter(
    blah=blah,
    nbar__gte=5
)
```

Comment: Ahhh so that's how annotate works. Thanks! Will accept when SO lets me sooner or later.

Comment: Would this also work if it was Count("bar__diff_model"). I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @acw: yes, if you want to count a model that is related to `bar`, you can use consecutive underscores. So then you would count the number of `diff_model`s related to the `bar` model related to that `Foo` object.

Comment: @acw , According to [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) ,  once you add  `Count("bar__diff_model")` as positional argument to `annotate()` , you can filter the  queryset (generated from the `annotate()` call) with new default field name `bar__diff_model__count` , e.g. `Foo.objects.annotate(Count("bar__diff_model")).filter(bar__diff_model__count__gt=123)` , it also works even it  look a little messy